# Displaying HTML content inside of a textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using the following code, to get my raw HTML string from the URL and display it inside of a (rich) textbox form:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TransparencyKey = Me.BackColor
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    RichTextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString("http://myurl.com/raw.php")
End Sub
```

The problem is that, the HTML string isn't converted and I can see the HTML tags inside of a textbox text I mean the `Hello <strong>World</strong>` isnt converted into the "Hello **World**".

I know I can use a WebBrowser object, but I would like to set its background color from the white to transparent and that is not allowed as far as I know. Another reason I dont want to use WebBrowser are links, because when the downloaded string has some `<a href="...">...</a>` tags, it would be converted but when I would like it to be opened with a default browser, instead of a typical location change in a box.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

A [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) cannot render HTML. What you need is a modified [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) control that handles HTML. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12172/An-extended-RichTextBox-to-save-and-load-quot-HTML) might help you get started atleast.

Then there's the [HtmlTextbox for Windows.Forms](http://winformhtmltextbox.codeplex.com/) control which might suite your needs.

Comment: I have tried it, but I can not get the background transparent instead of white - I'm setting the background to the `Color.Transparent` but it doesn't work. Also, when I click on the textbox, it doest minimalize my application.